# duplication problems in dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm in a first stage of creating dynamic forms. The problem is that when I click on the button of the form, a second time, forms doubles to add. The first time I click, it works correctly, just add a form.

code:

```
<div class="panel-body panel-primary">
    <ul id="lista" style="list-style-type: none">
        <li id="listap">
            <form id="formPregunta" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Pregunta:</label>
                    <input type="text"> </input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>tipo respuesta:</label>
                    <select>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <input class="bottom" type="button" value="agregar"> </input>
                 </div>
             </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready();

    $('input:button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var newF = $('#lista').html();
            $('#listap').after(newF);

    });
</script>
```

The documentation of the .html () function says: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

I do not know what will be the problem of duplication. Another problem is that the event will only function with the button on the first form, in other forms created is not working. Any kind of answer or advice is appreciated.

Comment: why you dont have name for form element (input, select) ?

Comment: You can use first() function to get first li. See my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709109/duplication-problems-in-dynamic-forms/32709224#32709224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var newF = $('#lista').html();
$('body').on('click', 'input:button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#listap').after(newF);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body panel-primary">
  <ul id="lista" style="list-style-type: none">
    <li id="listap">
      <form class="formPregunta">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Pregunta:</label>
          <input type="text" name="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>tipo respuesta:</label>
          <select name="select">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="bottom" type="button" value="agregar"></input>
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> You need to consider following points:

1. There should not be more than one `id` in a document
2. `var newF = $('#lista').html();` will return entire `DOM` present inside container hence you will get `n*2` elements on every click
3. As buttons which are appended later, does not have event `binded` hence you need to use `event delegation`
4. You should have `name` attribute to process form server side

Answer (score 1):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/jbs50jfy/)**

You can use [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) function to get first element like below

```
$(function () {
    $('input:button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var newF = $('#lista li').first().html();
            $('#listap').after(newF);

    });
});
```

This will get the content of the first `li` inside the `#lista`.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try below js code as well and also have a look demo at here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/agovomov/1/

Actually the solution is that just take first from dom from your `<li id="listap">` so it will not be make any duplications.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'input:button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newF = $('#lista form:first').html();
        $('#listap').after(newF);
    });
});
```

Thanks!